How do I use .htaccess to redirect a page only when it has a particular query string?
I want to setup a redirect for a page on my e-commerce site, which relies on query strings to display pages. I want to point a particular brand page to a new URL. Currently, the URL is:
https://example.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=11
and I want to direct this page to:
https://example.com/brand
But it also adds on other query strings sometimes too, for things like page number, which I also want to redirect, but without the page number, such as:
https://example.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=11&page=4
to
https://example.com/brand
However, I don't want to redirect any other brand, so I don't want this to redirect:
https://example.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=6
I tried this in .htaccess but it doesn't redirect at all:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} manufacturer_id=11
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/brand [R=302]

How can I achieve this?

According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=48c5fced-a5f1-4b7f-907e-0192dbe44a7e, this should work. (Only it will still append the original query string, so you might want to add the QSD flag as well.) If this doesn't work in your setup, then perhaps some other rewriting is interfering?

Thank you. It worked with the QSD flag and also required the L flag.
